# MDX filter condition set

Tags: filter, mdx

I am stuck with this issue. We have an MDX which needs to be updated to aggregate the last six months reports starting from the current month, so the MDX returns the aggregated data of last six months.

I am not an expert in MDX, Can someone please help, how this can be achieved?

**IDEA**: I was thinking to filter the reports of last six months, but I do not understand how this can be achieved syntactically.

```
 MEMBER [TIME].[_TIME1]  AS  'Aggregate({ [TIME].&[201401].lag(5):[TIME].&[201401] })'
```

**Actual MDX Query:**

```
with 

 set [reports] as 'Filter(
       [Report].[Report].Members,   
       Int([Measures].[Report Month Id])  = Int(([Measures].[Time Id], [TIME].&[201401] )) and
       Int([Measures].[Report Root Index Id])  =  Int(([Measures]. [Index Id],  [INDEX_1].[All].&[1]))
   )'

  set [Indexes] as 'Descendants([INDEX_1].[All].&[1])' 

   member [Measures].[N] as 'iif(Cstr([Measures].[Index Type Name]) = "Choice Index", ([Measures].[Direct Response Count]),  ([Measures].[Direct Case Count]))'   
   member [Measures].[Score] as '([Measures].[Direct Score])'   

   member [Measures].[Item Id]         as 'iif(isEmpty([Measures].[N]), null, [Measures].[Index Id])'       
    member [Measures].[Item Code]       as 'iif(isEmpty([Measures].[N]), null, [Measures].[Index Code])'       
    member [Measures].[Org Id]           as 'iif(isEmpty([Measures].[N]), null, [Measures].[Report Organisation Id] )'      


select    
     non empty crossjoin ( [reports] , [indexes] ) on rows ,                     
     {
        [Measures].[Org Id], [Measures].[Item Id], [Measures].[Item Code], [Measures].[N], [Measures].[Score] 
     } on columns      

from [REPORT_SCORE]      
where
(
  [ORGANISATION].&[3196]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ask for something like this?:

```
WITH SET [Last 6 Months]  AS 
                {   
                    PARALLELPERIOD([Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Day].[Month],
                                    5,  
                                    StrToMember("[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Day].[Day].&[" + Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00]")).Parent.Parent
                    :
                    StrToMember("[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Day].[Day].&[" + Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00]").Parent.Parent
                }
MEMBER [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Day].[AggregatedMonths] AS Aggregate([Last 6 Months])

SELECT [Measures].[Your Measure] ON COLUMNS,
[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Day].[AggregatedMonths] ON ROWS
FROM [Your Cube]
```